# Transposed parent/child table has incorrect row count

Tags: sql

We're loading engineering data into parent/child tables on a daily basis. To facilitate reporting for the users, I created a view which flattens the tables into a single tabular layout.

The number of records I get in the view (`As of today: 250,090`) does not match what is in the parent table (`As of today: 411,269`). This is the code for the view:

```
SEL   
     CAST(      A.END_TIME_TEXT AS TIMESTAMP(0) ) END_TIME,
      UPPER(A.OPER_NAME)  OPER_NAME,
       CAST(      A.START_TIME_TEXT AS TIMESTAMP(0)) START_TIME, 
      UPPER(A.PROC_NAME) PROC_NAME ,
       UPPER(A.PROC_REV_TEXT) PROC_REV_TEXT ,
       A.LOC_1_NAME,
       UPPER(A.LOC_1_TYPE_DESC) LOC_1_TYPE_DESC ,
       UPPER(A.LOC_2_NAME) LOC_2_NAME,
       UPPER(A.LOC_2_TYPE_DESC) LOC_2_TYPE_DESC,
       A.LOC_3_NAME ,
       UPPER(A.LOC_3_TYPE_DESC)  LOC_3_TYPE_DESC,
      A.LOC_4_NAME ,
       UPPER(A.LOC_4_TYPE_DESC) LOC_4_TYPE_DESC ,
      A.SER_NUM_TEXT , 
       UPPER(A.PROD_REV_TEXT) PROD_REV_TEXT ,
       UPPER(A.PROD_TYPE_DESC) PROD_TYPE_DESC,
       UPPER(A.OUTCOME_TEXT ) OUTCOME_TEXT,
       UPPER(A.DRIVER_PLAT_TEXT)  DRIVER_PLAT_TEXT,-
       CAST(A.DRIVER_REV_TEXT AS DECIMAL (1,0)) DRIVER_REV_TEXT ,
      A.ENABLE_PARM_DB_COMM_TEXT ,
      A.ENABLE_SFCS_COMM_TEXT ,
      A.FORCE_PARM_DB_UPD_TEXT , 
B.BIST_FAIL_CODE,    B.STB_CLIENT,
B.STB_CMNT,    B.COMPUTER_ID,
B.CONTRACT,    B.DTV_FAIL_CODE,
B.DTV_FAIL_DESC,    B.TEST_END_DATE,
B.TEST_END_TIME,    B.FAN_HALF_SPEED,
B.FAN_SPEED,    B.HDD_ID,
B.HDD_MDL,    B.HDD_POH, 
B.HDD_SER,    B.HDD_TEMP, 
B.LINE_ID,    B.MAC_ID,
B.OEM_NAME,    B.STB_MDL,
B.OPERATOR_ID,    B.RID,
B.RTE_ID,    B.RSSI1_24GHz,
B.RSSI1_5GHz,    B.RSSI2_24GHz,
B.RSSI2_5GHz,    B.SCRIPT_ID,
B.SCRIPT_VER,    B.SERVER_DRIVE_VER,
B.SITE_ID,    B.SLOT_ID,
B.SER_NUM,    B.SQ1_24GHz,
B.SQ1_5GHz,    B.SQ2_24GHz,
B.SQ2_5GHz,    B.SSID_24GHz,
B.SSID_5GHz,    B.TEST_START_DATE, 
B.TEST_START_TIME,     B.SWIN,
B.SWOUT,    B.TEST_RESULT,
B.TEST_TIME,    B.TIME_TO_FAIL,
B.STB_TYPE,    B.WORK_CENTER_ID   

FROM  AUTO_REPR_PAR A,
(
    SELECT  TEST_SEQ_NUM,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'BISTFAILCODE' THEN PARM_VAL END) BIST_FAIL_CODE, 
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'Client' THEN UPPER(PARM_VAL) END) STB_CLIENT,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'Comment' THEN UPPER(PARM_VAL) END) STB_CMNT,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'ComputerID' THEN UPPER(PARM_VAL) END) COMPUTER_ID,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'Contract' THEN UPPER(PARM_VAL) END) CONTRACT,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'DTVFAILCODE' THEN PARM_VAL END) DTV_FAIL_CODE,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'DTVFAILDESC' THEN PARM_VAL END) DTV_FAIL_DESC,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'EndDate' THEN CAST(PARM_VAL AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD') END) TEST_END_DATE,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'EndTime' THEN (PARM_VAL (TIME, FORMAT 'HHMISS'))  END)  TEST_END_TIME,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'FANHalfSpeed' THEN PARM_VAL END) FAN_HALF_SPEED,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'FANSpeed' THEN PARM_VAL END) FAN_SPEED,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'HDDID' THEN UPPER(PARM_VAL) END) HDD_ID,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'HDDModel' THEN UPPER(PARM_VAL) END) HDD_MDL,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'HDDPOH' THEN PARM_VAL END) HDD_POH, 
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'HDDSerial' THEN PARM_VAL END) HDD_SER,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'HDDTEMP' THEN PARM_VAL END)HDD_TEMP, 
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'LineID' THEN PARM_VAL END) LINE_ID,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'MACID' THEN PARM_VAL END) MAC_ID,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'Manufacturer' THEN UPPER(PARM_VAL) END)OEM_NAME,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'Model' THEN UPPER(PARM_VAL) END) STB_MDL,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'OperatorID' THEN UPPER(PARM_VAL) END) OPERATOR_ID,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'RID' THEN PARM_VAL END)RID,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'RouteID' THEN UPPER(PARM_VAL) END)RTE_ID,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'RSSI1_24GHz' THEN PARM_VAL END)RSSI1_24GHz,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'RSSI1_5GHz' THEN PARM_VAL END) RSSI1_5GHz,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'RSSI2_24GHz' THEN PARM_VAL END) RSSI2_24GHz,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'RSSI2_5GHz' THEN PARM_VAL END) RSSI2_5GHz,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'ScriptID' THEN PARM_VAL END)SCRIPT_ID,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'ScriptVer' THEN PARM_VAL END)SCRIPT_VER,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'ServerDriveVer' THEN PARM_VAL END)SERVER_DRIVE_VER,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'SiteID' THEN UPPER(PARM_VAL) END)SITE_ID,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'SlotID' THEN PARM_VAL END) SLOT_ID,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'SN' THEN PARM_VAL END) SER_NUM,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'SQ1_24GHz' THEN PARM_VAL END) SQ1_24GHz,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'SQ1_5GHz' THEN PARM_VAL END) SQ1_5GHz,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'SQ2_24GHz' THEN PARM_VAL END) SQ2_24GHz,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'SQ2_5GHz' THEN PARM_VAL END) SQ2_5GHz,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'SSID_24GHz' THEN PARM_VAL END)SSID_24GHz,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'SSID_5GHz' THEN PARM_VAL END) SSID_5GHz,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'StartDate' THEN  CAST(PARM_VAL AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD') END) TEST_START_DATE, 
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'StartTime' THEN (PARM_VAL (TIME, FORMAT 'HHMISS'))  END)  TEST_START_TIME,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'SWin' THEN PARM_VAL END) SWIN,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'SWout' THEN PARM_VAL END) SWOUT,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'TestResult' THEN UPPER(PARM_VAL) END) TEST_RESULT,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'TestTime' THEN PARM_VAL  END)  TEST_TIME,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'TimetoFail' THEN PARM_VAL END) TIME_TO_FAIL,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'TYPE' THEN UPPER(PARM_VAL) END) STB_TYPE,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'WorkCenterID' THEN UPPER(PARM_VAL) END) WORK_CENTER_ID
FROM 
(
  SELECT  TEST_SEQ_NUM,PARM_NAME,PARM_VAL,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TEST_SEQ_NUM ORDER BY TEST_SEQ_NUM) SEQ
  FROM AUTO_REPR_CHLD
) D
GROUP BY  TEST_SEQ_NUM
)
B,
RMA_MFR_MDL_PAR_XREF C
WHERE A.TEST_SEQ_NUM=B.TEST_SEQ_NUM   
AND  A.LOC_1_NAME=B.SITE_ID
AND  A.PROD_TYPE_DESC=C.MFR_SKU_CODE AND C.IRD_FLAG='Y'
```

This is the SQL to get the rowcount from the parent table

```
SELECT LOC_1_NAME,SUBSTR(END_TIME_TEXT,1,10), COUNT(*) FROM DDWP_V.AUTO_REPR_PAR GROUP BY 1,2
```

I removed the partition clause which selects from the child table, no change. What am I missing?

Comment: First off fix you join syntax! You are using pre-92 join syntax and it which makes your code difficult to read. Second why would you expect the count to be the same? You are `INNER JOIN`ing to several tables?

Comment: Why are you doing a ROW_NUMBER in the Derived Table? You're not using it at all. And there's a WHERE-condition on *C.IRD_FLAG='Y'* which is missing in the 2nd select.

Comment: You are inner-joining tables. An inner join can not only duplicate but also *eliminate* rows: if a row in one table has no match in the other table, the inner join will exclude it.

Comment: @AndriyM Thank you for explaining. It makes sense to use `left outer` joining since a parent table record equals many child table records.

Comment: No, you may be confusing things there. An outer join (including a left outer join) is about returning rows that don't have a match at the other side. If all the rows in the parent table had matches (one per each, twenty per each – doesn't matter), an inner join would do just fine and you'd get all the parent rows in the view. But, judging by the fact that a left (outer) join did help you, your parent table must have had rows that had *no* matches in the child table. (I actually have no idea if a left join is really what you need there, I'm just trying to help you to understand the difference.)

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that was inner joining instead of left outer joining. Fixed.

```
SEL   
CAST(      A.END_TIME_TEXT AS TIMESTAMP(0) ) END_TIME,
UPPER(A.OPER_NAME)  OPER_NAME,
...B.TIME_TO_FAIL,
B.STB_TYPE,
B.WORK_CENTER_ID
FROM  AUTO_REPR_PAR A
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(

SELECT  TEST_SEQ_NUM,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'BISTFAILCODE' THEN PARM_VAL END) BIST_FAIL_CODE, 
...
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'MANUFACTURER' THEN UPPER(PARM_VAL) END)OEM_NAME,
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'WORKCENTERID' THEN UPPER(PARM_VAL) END) WORK_CENTER_ID
FROM 
(
SELECT  TEST_SEQ_NUM,PARM_NAME,PARM_VAL 
FROM AUTO_REPR_CHLD
) D
GROUP BY  TEST_SEQ_NUM
)
B
ON
A.TEST_SEQ_NUM=B.TEST_SEQ_NUM   
AND  A.LOC_1_NAME=B.SITE_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN  RMA_MFR_MDL_PAR_XREF C
ON  A.PROD_TYPE_DESC=C.MFR_SKU_CODE AND C.IRD_FLAG='Y'
WHERE 
END_TIME IS NOT NULL
```

Thanks for everyone's help.